# How to create a listener for Intercepting and handling requests to Metamask in a browser extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, web3js, metamask, ethers.js

I want to create a PoC (Proof of Concept) for a simple extension that intercepts requests to Metamask and either accepts and forwards them to Metamask or blocks them.

I've seen applications like [Wallet Guard](https://github.com/wallet-guard/wallet-guard-extension), [The Interceptor](https://github.com/DarkFlorist/TheInterceptor), [PocketUniverse](https://github.com/refract-team/PocketUniverse), etc., that do the same thing, but they have so many features and complex code that it's difficult for me to extract the essentials for this proof of concept.

Could someone please guide me on creating a listener that intercepts these requests to Metamask?

I've tried these approaches:

- > chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(...
- > Browser.runtime.onConnect.addListener(...
- > window.ethereum.on(...

However, none of them have yielded results.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

---

The difference with other StackOverflow questions lies in the fact that in this case, we do not want to intercept HTTP requests but the communication between a page and Metamask or any digital asset wallet (I think the pages to communicate with these kinds of wallets use `window.ethereum` but I am not sure).